# Compiling ROS development files from source

Tags: compile, ros-comm, catkin, build-from-source, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the [source-based install documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source) for ROS Hydro to compile `ros_comm`. It seems as if the the `.rosinstall` file lists stable released versions of packages from https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release.git . However the development files for `ros_comm` is being hosted here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm .

My ultimate goal is to compile `roscpp` from source in a catkin workspace so every package in that workspace is built against the local [and patched] version of `roscpp`. I also want to be able to merge upstream changes when there is an update available. I tried to clone `ros_comm` from github ([the development repo](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm)) and make it, but it failed <del>because of unmet dependencies</del> (check the update below).

My questions is: What is the workflow to compile (and install) ROS core components in general (or `roscpp` in specific) from development repositories.

**UPDATE 1**

As @dirk mentioned, the current `hydro-devel` branch for `ros_comm` is unstable. That was the reason that building sources from github did not work. This is what I've done to overlay the latest stable version of `roscpp` in a catkin workspace based on @dirk and @demmeln answers.

```
mkdir roscppsrc_ws && cd roscppsrc_ws  
roslocate info roscpp > roscpp-stable.rosinstall 
# As the `hydro-devel` branch is unstable edit the `roscpp-stable.rosinstall` file
# and change version from `hydro-devel` to latest stable (e.g `1.9.50`)
wstool init src roscpp-stable.rosinstall
rosdep install --from-paths src --rosdistro hydro 
# Above did nothing on my computer with `ros-hydro-desktop` installed
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash  # Not an isolated build
catkin_make
```

To test the overlay I copied the `talker.cpp` and `listener.cpp` from `roscpp_tutorials` in a new package in `src/sample` of the same workspace. After a `catkin_make` I can confirm than the executables are linked against the local versions of `roscpp`:

```
ldd ./devel/lib/sample/talker | grep roscpp 
libroscpp.so => /home/mani/roscppsrc_ws/devel/lib/libroscpp.so (0x00007fc47ab80000)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110926/compiling-ros-development-files-from-source/) by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1704 on 2013-12-16

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-21**:
Just ot mention this in case you get strange behaviour/segfaults: In your described setup you might run intro trouble when the package you build ontop of your modified roscpp is linking also against a library from the Debian packages, which itself is linked against the Debian version of roscpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is highly not recommended to build all packages from their source repositories. While some of them might be stable others might not even build. Therefore you should use the latest released version from the gbp repositories.

E.g. the current version of roscpp in the development repo will not work with its released dependencies but requires the development versions of some dependencies.

If you really need some recent patches from the source repository you should just switch one repository from gbp to source and keep all other packages from gbp repos. The easiest workflow for that is:

- checkout the source repos which you want to use
- use rosdep to install all required dependencies fom Debian packages
- use the rosinstall_generator to generate a rosinstall file for a set of repositories on top of what you have installed / checked out from source

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2013-12-16**:
Thank you very much @dirk, I will give your solution a try and post the results here. So given this complexity, how people submit pull requests to core ros packages included in `ros_comm`?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-16**:
The above description is very generic and describes the procedure. Most of the times it is sufficient to checkout the sources of the package to patch (e.g. roscpp from ros_comm) and a higher level package which uses it and needs the patch/enhancement. So it should be fairly easy to setup workspace like this (even by hand).

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2013-12-20**:
Thank you very much. I updated the post with what worked for me.